# Fastest way to farm platinum in Rift?

Tags: rift

What are some of the fastest ways to farm platinum in Rift?

I'm currently a level 53 cleric with 810p and need to get to about 1200p in order to purchase my first rex from other players and unlock the auction house in game. Aside from getting lucky with having deeps lock boxes dropping, what could I do to speed up reaching the amount of platinum that I need in game?

Comment: *"...to purchase my first rex from other players and unlock the auction house in game"*
One time $5 investment for opening AH at very beginning is the most wise approach to play this game and make platinum during leveling.
Furthermore, it is very easy to create personal guild for extra bank space.
Personally, I payed for unlocking BL souls and extra character slots to be able to play every possible calling/builds.

Comment: Considering I only needed a little over 200 platinum at the time that I posted this message to unlock the auction house without spending real money, spending $5 would have been a bit of a waste. I've considered spending money to purchase things like the SL souls, however if I do, that will mostly be to support the game developers. Personally I find it more fun earning things the long way since leads you to having a bigger sense of accomplishment when you finally get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right at this moment, prices for many raw materials like wood and metals are quite high (at least on my shard). Karthite, Elm and Frazzleweed already had good prices to begin with, so gathering runs could rake in some serious cash.

The reason for the current high pricess is because crafting dailies now grant Dendrome notoriety (Achyati/Hailol/Empyreal Alliance), so people are using more of these materials and buying them.

That being said, if you don't have the auction house enabled, you're in a bit of a catch 22. You can try pawning materials in chat, but it will usually get you a somewhat lower price.

Comment: About how much does Elm and Frazzleweed sell for? Right now I've only got mining and have been gathering up as much karthite as possible so once I purchase my first rex and unlock the AH I can quickly make some more platinum. If the other two sell for a lot then I might go ahead and get rid of one of my other professions just to farm more platinum in game. My goal is to get either 3-4 rex to unlock SL souls and possibly some convenience items in the store

Comment: I imagine it depends on which server you play on, plus prices fluctuate a lot at the moment. You probably shouldn't bother with Frazzleweed, but Elm is 1.2p to 2p on my shard.

Answer (score 0):

The information given here is good but I would like to add my own personal suggestion to farming the plat. Instead of posting in chat trying to sell your items you could go on a farm from say for some high end cloth or hides or even ore and use the rift store to sell all of this. The real best thing to farm and sell in the rift store is high end cloth. Like lanzan cloth. Find the right spot kill the guys that drops the cloth and farm for about 2 or so hours until you have say 5 or so stacks of the stuff. With those stacks and the drops that you got from killing the guys you should end up will getting some where from 20 to 40 maybe even 50 gold in under a hour. Now some people may reply and say its wasting the cloth or even the materials them selfs and to a point they are right but if you really want the plat so bad that works. It may take you a bit longer but consider this. 99 lanzan = 1 stack which sells in the AH for about 20 plat so selling 1 stack to the rift store is 6 plat each plus the drops that you got will add up to more then what you would get if you asked for 10 a stack. The key is if you post want to sell 4 stacks of laznaz cloth in chat your price will have to be much lower then that of what its posted in the AH. Again if 1 stack in AH is 10 your price must drop down below 10 plat. So its just safer to sell all that to the rift store take your 20 plat and repeat. Do this enough and save your have 1000 in no time.

Answer (score 0):

The three best ways to make plat in rift are, 1 - once you have omen sight gather artifacts, there are zones where you can find as many as 100 artifacts per hour, sell 100 for 50-60 plat to dreamweaver, save the epic and rare ones. 2 - Gathering professions, especially mining and foraging, some woods and bars sell for almost 1 plat each, 3 - do greenscale blight (not the chronicle) but you have to be very strong (level 65) to do it alone, but if you do, you can make 120 plat in that dungeon alone.